# copy to destination and delete from source using single command

Tags: gsutil

Wanted to copy files to destination bucket and delete the same from source if it is success which is from two different bucket in different region.
Is that gsutil cp command support this using -d or any suggestion will be great helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for not noticing it properly, i was able to do that using gsutil -m mv gs://s_bucketname/foldername gs://d_bucketname/foldername